# how to implement simple like button in listview of each item

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-button

[image]

I have certain entries in my list view item. There I have a simple "like button" (not facebook like button). You can see the above mentioned SCREENSHOT; for the reference.
The moment I click on like button; i want the like button color to be changed and the like button color should remain same(*changed on like*) when I'll login again.

Also, all the entries must get filled in Database with cust_id, bus_id, Offer_id using json; that I know very well.

When I again click on the same button(like button), whose color has been changed. It must be changed back to the default color and data must get removed from database.

How can I do this...?
1. How to get value of click button.
2. How to bring back the changed color to default; once the button  has been re-clicked.

Plz suggest me...

this is button code

```
holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clicked) {
                    holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon_hover);
                } else {
                    holder.b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
                }
                clicked = true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a listener to the button and using ValueAnimator you can change the button color and reverse it back when you click again.

Here is a simple and best approach to achieve your scenario. Add the onClick listener for the button in your list item like this.. I have explained each line ..

```
    // set a default background color to the button
    placeHolder.likeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    placeHolder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ValueAnimator buttonColorAnim = null; // to hold the button animator

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // first time this will be null
            if(buttonColorAnim != null){
                // reverse the color
                buttonColorAnim.reverse();
                // reset for next time click
                buttonColorAnim = null;
                // add your code here to remove from database
            }
            else {
                final Button button = (Button) v;
                // create a color value animator
                buttonColorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
                // add a update listener for the animator.
                buttonColorAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                        // set the background color
                        button.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                    }
                });
                // you can also set a delay before start
                //buttonColorAnim.setStartDelay(2000); // 2 seconds
                // start the animator..
                buttonColorAnim.start();
                // add your code here to add to database
            }
        }
    });
```

This will change the button color on your first click and then revert the color back on the next click. You can also set a delay to change the color.

Note: You have to set the default button color based on your logic.

Comment: Sir can u kindly explain what to do with this line? ` final Button button = (Button) v;`

Comment: Sir please help for this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321485/how-to-change-color-of-button-when-being-click-and-revert-back-to-default-color

Answer (score 2):

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!check)
                {

                    personViewHolder.img_like_job.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumbsup_blue);
                    check = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    personViewHolder.img_like_job.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumbsup);
                    check = false;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom adapter for your listview(it has own layout.xml),and you can set your clicklistener in it.

You can change color or what you want. Actually I did have project like you want.I put some link if you can t do it.

Comment: I have implemented the custom adapter in list view and gets the data successfully in a proper way.
Please provide some useful link, to implement the like button process.

Comment: so your custom adapter has its own layout? then you can put there like button then you can put onclick event in your adatper class

Comment: holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { } });

Comment: and in your click event you should use ***.position(x);*** because it gives you which line you are on

Comment: ok you hold it manuelly, I mean you can set a **list** which holds which buttons are clicked or not clicked.its size as same as your **list.length()** then when a person press click on like button you should set your list like this : ***my_list[mylist.get(position)]=1***if it is 1 it is clicked then you check it like that

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. use `setOnClickListener()` on the `button`.

eg.

```
viewHolder.imgVwFbLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
   @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO :
         // 1. make webservice call to update like status (Assuming a web service call)
         // 2. Implement a callback for webservice call, to get the status of request.
            if(success) 
             a) change the colour of like btn. and insert the data in Db.
             b) Also maintain a column in db for likestatus(by default set it false).                 
            } 
        }
   );
```

1. Assuming you are fetching the data from db when you login, you can check the likestatus and set the color of button accordingly.

Comment: what can i do when user again click on this button....how can click button back to its original stage...