# How to change color of button when being click,and revert back to default color in next click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `like` button in my `RecyclerView`,what I want is when user hit the `like` button for the 1st time,the button background color will change to `red` color,and when the same user hit the `like` button,the button will change back to default color which is `white`.

I checked for few SO question,but still havent get what I want.So far my solution is like below,doesnt produce any error but when clicked the button,nothing happen.

```
 likeButton =(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.likeButton);

 //here for user like the post
 holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean clicked = true;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!clicked){
                    holder.likeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    clicked = true;

                    //here i will update the database

                }else{
                    holder.likeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    clicked = false;
                     //here i will update the database
                }


            }
        });
```

I checked this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977003/4332049) too,so I modified my code as below,but still nothing happens when the button is clicked.

```
 holder.likeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ValueAnimator buttonColorAnim = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(buttonColorAnim != null){
                buttonColorAnim.reverse();
                buttonColorAnim = null;
              //here i will update the database
            }else{
                final Button button = (Button) v;//here is the line I dont undestand
                buttonColorAnim = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), Color.RED, Color.WHITE);

                buttonColorAnim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                        // set the background color
                        button.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                    }
                  //here i will update the database
                });

                buttonColorAnim.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Somebody please point out what I'm missing,what I want is change button color programmatically when being click for 1st time,and change back to default for next click(which avoid multiple like from a same user).

Comment: Your first example appears to be correct, however, your `clicked` variable  has assigned value `true`, which means `!clicked` is always false and your code is never executed.

Comment: so i should assign false for the 1st example? @MatusMak

Comment: reason of downvote?

Comment: it's not from me, I'm not downvoting questions as it discourages people from asking, but I guess somebody don't liked the way you have written your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to this hope this can help you...

**In XML**

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClick"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:text="click"/>
```

**In Adapter Class**

```
  boolean click = true;


        holder.btnClick.setTag(position);
        holder.btnClick.setId(position);
        holder.btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (click) {
                    holder.btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    click = false;
                } else {
                    holder.btnClick.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    click = true;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a selector file. Create a file in drawable folder like color_change.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_focused"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/button_default"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and declare it in the button like this

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/color_change"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, but I used images insted of colour. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `clicked` or not condition, make and use condition from you update database for `like` and `dislike` operation. So, In click-listener get data previously user like or not then change background and update database as per new click.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your row.xml file in the main layout :

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: this one is for what ya??

Comment: To make the button clickable, it just brings the focus to the button rather than the list of your's. Have you tried it !

Answer (score 0):

Have  a look at this. Here, I changed the button text color on click. First time, all buttons appear white and after click it toggles between red and white as you expected. --

//LikeAdapter.java

```
public class LikeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LikeAdapter.LikeHolder> {

    public LikeAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public LikeAdapter.LikeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.like_item,parent,false);
        return new LikeHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final LikeAdapter.LikeHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.red_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (holder.red_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.red_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.white_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.red_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.white_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        holder.white_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.white_btn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.red_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.white_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    holder.red_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.white_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public class LikeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private Button red_btn, white_btn;
        public LikeHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            red_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.red_btn);
            white_btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.white_btn);
            red_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            white_btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }
    }
}
```

//like_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Red"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/white_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="White"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```