# Toggle FloatingActionButton Icon when Clicking On It

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have two drawable pictures, initially FAB is set to R.drawable.icon1, I want to set it to R.drawable.icon2 when clicking on it, and setting it back to icon1 when clicking one more time on it and so on...

Is there a way to do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is the method for setting icon : fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.icon1));
Use some flag for changing icon.

Comment: Hi please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321485/how-to-change-color-of-button-when-being-click-and-revert-back-to-default-color/43322291#43322291

Comment: Thank you @BharathKumar that's the easiest way to do so

Comment: Thank you @DileepPatel it's pretty much the same idea of using boolean flag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this helps, we have a boolean `flag` which denotes the current icon visible in your fab.

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
boolean flag = true; // true if first icon is visible, false if second one is visible.

fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(flag){

                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon2));
                flag = false;

            }else if(!flag){

                fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icon1));
                flag = true;

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah! I think the best way as you said is to use a boolean flag. thanks @Chirag

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following extension function for Kotlin to make the operation easier.

```kotlin
fun FloatingActionButton.icon(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0) {
    setImageResource(id)
}

fun FloatingActionButton.backgroundColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int = 0) {
    backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes))
}

fun FloatingActionButton.iconColor(@ColorRes colorRes: Int = 0) {
    imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes))
}
```

Sample:

```kotlin
var flag = true

binding.fabToggleService.setOnClickListener {
    flag = !flag

    if (flag) {
        binding.fabToggleService.apply {
            icon(R.drawable.ic_round_stop_24)
            iconColor(R.color.white)
            backgroundColor(R.color.md_red_400)

    } else {
        binding.fabToggleService.apply {
            icon(R.drawable.ic_round_play_arrow_24)
            iconColor(R.color.white)
            backgroundColor(R.color.md_blue_400)
    }

}
```

You can see the action live, see comment with link of one of my apps

Comment: See in action app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codelaby.app.batteryalerts